# PL/pgSQL: Comparing Successive Rows

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have the function, `get_untracked_moves`, below. My goal is to, for all data between two date ranges, find successive events which are farther than `p_separation_distance` apart.

E.g.:

If event 1 and event 2 are 40 m apart when p_separation_distance is 100m, a record would be returned with event 1's associated cont_name as the `source_name` and event 2's cont_name as the `target_name`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_untracked_moves(IN p_since_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, IN p_before_date TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, IN p_separation_distance INTEGER)
    RETURNS TABLE ( id INTEGER,
            asset_name CHARACTER VARYING,
            source_name CHARACTER VARYING,
            target_name CHARACTER VARYING,
            source_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
            target_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,            
            source_lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
            source_lon DOUBLE PRECISION,            
            target_lat DOUBLE PRECISION,
            target_lon DOUBLE PRECISION ) AS $$

    DECLARE     
        d_previous_location GEOMETRY;
        d_previous_name CHARACTER VARYING;
        d_previous_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE;

        d_cur record;
    BEGIN
         -- Begin @ 0,0
         d_previous_location := st_setsrid(st_makepoint(0,0), 4326);
        d_previous_name := '';
        d_previous_time := NULL;

        FOR    d_cur
        IN
            SELECT
                rank() OVER (PARTITION BY events.asset_id ORDER BY events.event_time) AS idx,
                tags.id asset_id,
                tags.name asset_name,
                d_previous_name,
                conts.name cont_name,
                events.position,
                events.event_time evt_time

            FROM 
                events
            JOIN 
                assets tags ON tags.id = events.asset_id
            JOIN 
                assets conts ON conts.id = events.container_asset_id
            WHERE
                events.event_time >= p_since_date
            AND
                events.event_time <= p_before_date
        LOOP
                 IF (d_previous_time = NULL) THEN
                    d_previous_time :=  events.event_time;
                 END IF;

                IF (st_distancesphere(events.position, d_previous_location)>=p_separation_distance) THEN
                    RETURN NEXT;
                END IF;

                d_previous_location := events.position;
                d_previous_name := conts.name;
                d_previous_time :=  events.event_time;

        END LOOP;   
    END;
    $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The function creates fine, but when I go to run it with:

```
select * from get_untracked_moves('2015-11-1', '2015-12-1', 10000);
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "events"
LINE 1: SELECT (st_distancesphere(events.position, d_previous_locati...
                                  ^
QUERY:  SELECT (st_distancesphere(events.position, d_previous_location)>=p_separation_distance)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "get_untracked_moves" line 41 at IF

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "events"
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function "get_untracked_moves" line 41 at IF
```

What am I missing here? I thought the inclusion of `FROM events` in my `SELECT` statement was enough.

Comment: You should read up on the `LAG()` window function and do it all in SQL...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'd really like to do this is plpgsql though; there's some other logic I've removed in an effort to make this as small to reproduce as possible.

Comment: `events` does not exist inside the loop. Refer to that column  as `d_cur.position`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto that did it. I've got another, non-related issue now. Feel free to post as an answer. A reference to why this is so, in said answer would be most appreciated :)

Comment: @LukasEder perhaps this wasn't your intention, but after rewriting the query to use `select *

FROM 
    events
   JOIN 
    assets tags ON tags.id = events.asset_id
   JOIN 
    assets conts ON conts.id = events.container_asset_id
   WHERE
    events.event_time >= '2015-11-1'
   AND
    events.event_time <= '2015-12-1'
   AND
    ST_Distance (lag(events.position) over (order by events.event_time), events.position) > 1000`, I'm getting, `ERROR:  window functions not allowed in WHERE clause
LINE 14:     ST_Distance (lag(events.position) over (order by events....
                     `

Comment: @LukasEder Or did you mean "do it all in SQL" to mean something else?

Comment: I meant precisely that. Indeed, you cannot use window functions outside of the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, but I see you've already accepted a solution

Comment: @LukasEder I ended up using a query quite similar to ClodoaldoNeto's. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each pass of the loop is given the value of the record containing the corresponding row of the select result set. So `events` is not visible inside the loop. In instead use `d_cur.position` to refer to that column.

BTW, as commented to your question, you should really use the `lag` window function and get rid of the messy loop.

As a suggestion check this query:

```
select idx, asset_id, asset_name, previous_name, cont_name, position, evt_time
from (
    select
        rank() over (partition by e.asset_id order by e.event_time) as idx,
        st_distancesphere(
            e.position,
            lag(e.position, 1, e.position) over (order by e.event_time)
        ) >= p_separation_distance as b,
        t.id as asset_id,
        t.name as asset_name,
        lag(c.name, 1) as previous_name,
        c.name as cont_name,
        e.position,
        e.event_time as evt_time
    from 
        events e
        inner join 
        assets tags on t.id = e.asset_id
        inner join 
        assets c on c.id = e.container_asset_id
    where
        e.event_time >= p_since_date
        and
        e.event_time <= p_before_date
) s
where b
```